# Table Views - dropdown filter on each columns

Tags: views

I have a simple view, *Format:Table*, and I want to expose filter on each column (dropdown list).

But some of my table fields are *Global: PHP* so I cannot add them on the *FILTER CRITERIA* section....

Is there a simple module that create filter on each column?

Comment: What's in `Global:PHP`? If what's in there is not coming from database then how do you want to filter it? It's not possible. By the time Drupal gets to that PHP code all the data has been pulled out of the tables already.

Comment: Yes I use it to retrieve a title from a node ID. And I would like to add a dropdown list for each different title displayed